# How can I specify when creating a web request that I want to receive certain fields from [FromBody]

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am creating a web service for user authentication. (I am new in c# using entity framework core)

```
    [HttpPost, Route("login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Usuario>> Login([FromBody] User user) 
    {
      
    }
```

my model User has the next fields:

```
{
 name,
 password,
 phone,
 email
}
```

I don't know how to specify so that from the client side, my users can see the fields that my web service needs to receive and when I use some plugin to document my API it can be clearly seen that I ONLY need the `name` to be sent and `password` only.

I think of something like that, I hope to make myself understand:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Usuario>> Login([FromBody] string email, [FromBody] string password)
```

so in this way when the API is documented, I would like it to be understood that you need to send `email` and `password` only

and so from the client side

```
{"password": "212346", "email": "myemail@hotmail.com" }
```

is sent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view model should contain ONLY the fields each API method requires.  If there are fields in your request that are not required, they should not be in the method body.   If you use something like Swagger to document your API, then it will show just the fields required for each method.

Generally, I hear questions like this when the developer tries to use a DTO or even a database entity as a view model (both of which are incorrect uses).

I make sure each API method has a different view model (even if the contents are identical), because most of the time, eventually they will be different, but not always at the start.